# Rails : nested resources issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, nested, relationship

I'm newbie in RoR and currently on my first app.
I've got 3 models : Event, Place and Order

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :places
end

class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :number, :price, :event_id
  has_one :order
  belongs_to :event
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :place_number, :price, :place_id
  belongs_to :place
end
```

Routes, btw when I had deeply nested it worked, at least NEW action gave no errors.

```
    resources :events do
       resources :places 
    end

    resources :places do
     resources :orders
  end
```

I've got the problem with creating new order. Error is

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in OrdersController#new

Couldn't find Event without an ID
```

Here goes my OrdersController(not full) cause its failing on the first line of my code

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Once more what I supposed to do. I'm creating new order by getting info about place and event user clicked on. So I think I need those variables in NEW action and later in CREATE to get info about event and place.

Comment: can you show how you build the link to go to the new action of the orders controller?

Comment: There's no value for the key `:id` in the `params` hash for the `new` action. If nested under `:places`, you'll have a `params[:place_id]` (and if under event, `params[:event_id]`).

Comment: The link to the new order is built according to rake routes and looks like new_place_order_path(@place)